# Django передача аргумента из метода в метод

Tags: django

Проблема заключается в том что у меня есть корзина, которая сохраняется в сессию и после удачно созданного заказа данная сессия/корзина очищается полностью. А у корзины есть метод, который возвращает сумму товара и после очищения корзины товаров он возвращает `0`, что логично, но мне нужно сохранить сумму в переменную и передать эту переменную второму методу, который принимает идентификатор заказа клиента, не изменяя `url`, то есть я хочу чтобы в `url` был только идентификатор, но никак не идентификатор + сумма. Мне нужно передать аргумент из одного метода в другой. Сейчас я покажу что я имею ввиду.

**views.py**

```
def order_create(request):
  cart = Cart(request) # сессия
  sum = cart.get_total_price() # значение суммы сохраняется в переменную
  if request.method == 'POST':
      form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         # сохранение данных
         cart.clear_session() # очищаем сессию после успешного заказа
      return redirect(reverse('order:order_success', kwargs={'pk':order.id})) # как передать здесь еще и переменную `sum`
  else:
       return HttpResponse('y')
```

Передается идентификатор заказа пользователя методу order_success

```
def order_success(request, pk, sum):
   print(sum)
   # обработка данных и возврат страницы с данными
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^order/(?P<pk>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)$', views.order_success, name='order_success'),
```

Как можно передать значение в метод, не выпуская значение `sum` в `url` на всеобщее лицезрение. Прошу помощи у вас!

Comment: Почему бы не сохранять в заказе информацию о его стоимости?

Comment: Вот да, если у вас есть модель вроде `Order`, то в ней так и напрашивается поле вида `total_price = models.DecimalField`

Comment: спасибо, ребят)